# Debian Bookworm, systemd, and how EXT4 quota works?

Tags: systemd, ext4, quota

I have a fresh Debian 12 system and I'm trying to turn on and enforce EXT4 filesystem quota. I read a lot of `man` and some other sources, for example this one from Red Hat: https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/9/html/managing_file_systems/limiting-storage-space-usage-on-ext4-with-quotas_managing-file-systems

And I cannot make it work and after several hours of trying I'm confused. I do not know, if there is a sane way to do this or am I missing something. Let's try it on a loop file.

```
vagrant@bookworm:~$ sudo dd status=progress if=/dev/zero of=ext4_fs bs=1M count=1000
1000+0 records in
1000+0 records out
1048576000 bytes (1.0 GB, 1000 MiB) copied, 0.595179 s, 1.8 GB/s

vagrant@bookworm:~$ sudo mkfs.ext4 ext4_fs 
mke2fs 1.47.0 (5-Feb-2023)
Discarding device blocks: done                            
Creating filesystem with 256000 4k blocks and 64000 inodes
Filesystem UUID: 2d5eedba-eada-4b9f-ba88-e182b3ff24fa
Superblock backups stored on blocks: 
    32768, 98304, 163840, 229376
Allocating group tables: done                            
Writing inode tables: done                            
Creating journal (4096 blocks): done
Writing superblocks and filesystem accounting information: done

vagrant@bookworm:~$ sudo tune2fs -O quota ext4_fs 
tune2fs 1.47.0 (5-Feb-2023)

vagrant@bookworm:~$ mkdir mountpoint
vagrant@bookworm:~$ sudo mount ext4_fs mountpoint/
vagrant@bookworm:~$ ls mountpoint/
lost+found

vagrant@bookworm:~$ sudo quotaon -v -p mountpoint/
group quota on /home/vagrant/mountpoint (/dev/loop0) is on (accounting)
user quota on /home/vagrant/mountpoint (/dev/loop0) is on (accounting)
project quota on /home/vagrant/mountpoint (/dev/loop0) is off
```

So far so good. Now, are files `aquota.user` or `aquota.group` required? If so, they should be created automatically using the `quotacheck` command:

```
vagrant@bookworm:~$ sudo quotacheck -cugm mountpoint/
quotacheck: Cannot find filesystem to check or filesystem not mounted with quota option.
```

Weird. When I remount the system `ro`, the command starts, but obviously cannot work properly and write those files:

```
vagrant@bookworm:~$ sudo quotacheck -cugm mountpoint/
quotacheck: Cannot create new quotafile /home/vagrant/mountpoint/aquota.user.new: Read-only file system
quotacheck: Cannot initialize IO on new quotafile: Read-only file system
```

When I try to `enforcing` the quota, I add `usrquota` to `fstab` and reboot.

```
/home/vagrant/ext4_fs /home/vagrant/mountpoint ext4 rw,nodev,nosuid,defaults,usrquota 0 0
```

Quotas are enforced, but `aquota.user` file is missing, I still cannot run `quotacheck`, and now `systemd` is added to the mix, with failed `quotaon.service`:

```
vagrant@bookworm:~$ sudo systemctl status quotaon.service 
× quotaon.service - Enable File System Quotas
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/quotaon.service; static)
     Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Sun 2023-09-24 15:18:07 UTC; 8min ago
       Docs: man:quotaon(8)
    Process: 359 ExecStart=/sbin/quotaon -aug (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
   Main PID: 359 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
        CPU: 1ms

Sep 24 15:18:07 bookworm systemd[1]: Starting quotaon.service - Enable File System Quotas...
Sep 24 15:18:07 bookworm quotaon[359]: quotaon: using . on /dev/loop0 [/home/vagrant/mountpoint]: File exists
Sep 24 15:18:07 bookworm systemd[1]: quotaon.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Sep 24 15:18:07 bookworm systemd[1]: quotaon.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Sep 24 15:18:07 bookworm systemd[1]: Failed to start quotaon.service - Enable File System Quotas.
```

And there is also:

```
vagrant@bookworm:~$ sudo systemctl status systemd-quotacheck.service
● systemd-quotacheck.service - File System Quota Check
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/systemd-quotacheck.service; static)
     Active: active (exited) since Sun 2023-09-24 15:18:07 UTC; 12min ago
       Docs: man:systemd-quotacheck.service(8)
    Process: 354 ExecStart=/lib/systemd/systemd-quotacheck (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
   Main PID: 354 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
        CPU: 3ms

Sep 24 15:18:07 bookworm systemd[1]: Starting systemd-quotacheck.service - File System Quota Check...
Sep 24 15:18:07 bookworm systemd[1]: Finished systemd-quotacheck.service - File System Quota Check.
```

What is the sane way in 2023 to configure disk quotas?

Kind regards.

Comment: I seem to recall you have to touch the quotas file, and then use the `-f` (force) option on quotacheck.    But quota data may have been moved from teh quotas file to metadata in the filesystem.

Comment: I read something similar in the in the `man`. I'm happy without those files, but then when I'm trying to enforce the quotas with mount option `usrquota` I get failed systemd services. It probably shouldn't fail and this tells me that somethig is not right.

Comment: there: https://ext4.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Quota (no quota files anymore)

Comment: @A.B yes. I set `tune2fs -O quota -Q usrquota`, for example, to enable only user quota. But this results in the `accounting` state. When I try to enforce it with `usrquota` mount option (this is still needed, right? If no, how to enforce quotas without it?), I get `quotaon.service` failed. I can disable it, mask it, etc, because even with this unit failing enforcing apparently works. But *something* is not right. Why `quotaon.service` is needed, why it fails. I would like to do it the proper way.

Comment: Yes, I know how to set quotas, I set them almost on a daily basis :) I'm interested in why `quotaon.service` fails and why it is needed and if it is needed. This is now probably the only thing that fails when mounting a filesystem with `usrquota` enabled. The setup is what is not clear for me.

Comment: `-p` prints the status of quota, I know. Try to set enforcing between reboots automatically and check the status of `quotaon.service`.

Comment: Just realize your problem is with integration. First time I'm actually testing quota... so can't really help (but thanks to have got me see how this works).

Comment: So, you should not enable quotas in fstab until you have quotas working.  This means a successful quotacheck run, and a quotaon command that is reflected in mount options (from mtab or /proc/mounts).   Likely quotacheck is failing because you don't have the right options yet.

Comment: Note that both quotacheck and quotaon might give nonsensical error messages, where the real error is in the kernel buffers, and likely /var/log/syslog or /var/log/messages or something.

Comment: Apart from failling `quotaon.service` quotas are working fine it seems. No errors or other bad messages in logs. For now, I masked `quotaon.service`. This leaves `tune2fs -O quota` plus `usrquota` option in `fstab`. This enables all required quotas and sets `enforcing`. Curiously, I found similar bug in Debian several years ago: https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=788963

Answer (score 0):

You don't need quota files with ext4, since the quota is handled internally and atomically with ext4 transactions, so the quota files *shouldn't* get out of sync with the actual files owned by each user/group/project.  If they do, then e2fsck will repair them.